# Creating a sub array from a larger array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a loop that takes in a nested array and makes a sub-array of two consecutive tuples at a time. The input array may be something like this

```
arr = [['A','B'],['C','D'],['E','F'],['G','H'],['I','J'],['K','L'],
      ['M','N'],['O','P']]

Output: ['A','B'],['C','D']
        ['E','F'],['G','H']
        ['I','J'],['K','L']
        ['M','N'],['O','P']
```

I have tried out various loops, like

```
arr.each_slice(2) do |k,m|
   new_arr=[k,m]
   puts new_arr
end
```

and

```
 arr.each_slice(2) { |k,m| puts(k,m) }
```

What is wrong with this? In both the cases, the output is

```
A
B
C
D .....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just how `puts` is treating arrays in ruby 1.9, [it prints each element on a new line](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-puts). The result is what you want, it just looks differently when printed :) Try printing with `.inspect`, for example.

```
arr = [['A','B'],['C','D'],['E','F'],['G','H'],['I','J'],['K','L'],
      ['M','N'],['O','P']]

arr.each_slice(2) do |k,m|
   new_arr = [k,m]
   puts new_arr.inspect
end
# >> [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
# >> [["E", "F"], ["G", "H"]]
# >> [["I", "J"], ["K", "L"]]
# >> [["M", "N"], ["O", "P"]]
```

---

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-puts

> ### puts(obj, ...) → nil
>
> Writes the given objects to ios as with IO#print. Writes a record separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence. If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line. If called without arguments, outputs a single record separator.

```
$stdout.puts("this", "is", "a", "test")
```

produces:

```
this
is
a
test
```